# BeautifulSoup returns empty td tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some info from this url "http://baloncestoenvivo.feb.es/Game/1881578". And I want to get all the info that there is inside a table which is inside a div with this `id = "keyfacts-playbyplay-content-scroll"`

I access to this table with this code:

```
table = page_soup.find(id="keyfacts-playbyplay-content-scroll").findAll("table", {"class" : "twelve even"})
```

Then, print "table" to see what I get and I get one tr with no data. However, using firefox or chrome console we can see that there are 799 table rows with data!!!

This is what a I get when I print "table" in python console:

```
>> table
<table class="twelve even">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Tiempo</th>
<th colspan="2">Cuarto</th>
<th colspan="2">Puntuación</th>
<th colspan="8">Acción</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<!-- ko foreach: LINES -->
<tr>
<td class="text-center" colspan="2" data-bind="text : time"></td>
<td class="text-center" colspan="2" data-bind="text : quarter"></td>
<td colspan="2" data-bind="text : scoreA()==null ? '' : scoreA()+'-'+scoreB()" style="color:#FB0127; text-align: center"></td>
<td colspan="8" data-bind="text : text"></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this is what we can see in the console:

[image]

Why don't get the same? All the tr tags with their td tags with information?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the table are dynamically generated through JavaScript. That's why the page source doesn't have them. `requests` module gets you the page source without the execution of the JavaScript, which is the reason why you are seeing incomplete data.

If you check the `XHR` tab under the `Network` tab in the dev tools, a request is being sent to http://baloncestoenvivo.feb.es/api/KeyFacts/1881578 which returns the data in the form of JSON. You can parse this data using `requests` module and its built-in `.json()` function.

Only thing is, you need to pass the following headers. Without them, the website is blocking the script and you'll see `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'}

r = requests.get('http://baloncestoenvivo.feb.es/api/KeyFacts/1881578', headers=headers)
data = r.json()
```

You can now get all the table values from the `data` variable. To see its structure, use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module.

For example, to get the player names and corresponding points, you can use this:

```
for player in data['SCOREBOARD']['TEAM'][0]['PLAYER']:
    name = player['name']
    points = player['pts']
    print(name, points)
```

Output:

```
A. ELONU 6
L. NICHOLLS GONZALEZ 10
S. DOMINGUEZ FERNANDEZ 13
L. QUEVEDO CAÑIZARES 0
M. ASURMENDI VILLAVERDE 5
F. ABDI 0
E. DE SOUZA MACHADO 13
L. GIL COLLADO 0
K. GIVENS 12
D. MOSS 2
A. ROBINSON 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind it is that we need to use a browser emulator like `Selenium` to render this dynamic content generated by `javascript`.
If we try to request this data just with requests we'll not get the `td`s that you're looking for. I would recommend official Selenium Documentation or a Youtube tutorial on this library, it is very easy to use once you get a grasp of things.

[Selenium Documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


asdf = requests.get('http://baloncestoenvivo.feb.es/Game/1881578').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(asdf, 'lxml')


tabl = soup.find('div',{'id':'keyfacts-playbyplay-content-scroll'}).find('div',{'class':'twelve columns'})

print(tabl)
```

This doesn't work and it will return only a portion of the HTML that doesn't contain the information you're looking for (i.e. table elements)

Comment: Hi!!! I want to thank you for your help, but finally for me is more usefull to get the json. Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!!